# implementing scrollview animation in react-native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-animated

I have two components- one consists of a scrollview and a function that is being fired on scroll of it and the other contains a footer whose height I want to change on scroll.

The first component with the scrollView goes like this--

```
const FOOTER_MAX_HEIGHT = 60;
const FOOTER_MIN_HEIGHT = 0;
const FOOTER_SCROLL_DISTANCE = FOOTER_MAX_HEIGHT - FOOTER_MIN_HEIGHT;
class Home extends React.Component {
  state= {
   scrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
  }

    onScroll = () => {
    console.log("scrolling");
    Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY }} }]);
  }

  renderFooter = () => {
    const footerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, FOOTER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [FOOTER_MAX_HEIGHT, FOOTER_MIN_HEIGHT],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
    return (
        <Footer
          footerHeight = {footerHeight}
        />
    );
  }

  render(){
    return(
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <List onScroll={this.onScroll}/>
      {this.renderFooter()}
     </View>

    )
  }
}
```

In list.js, I have a scrollview with a function like this

```
class List extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <ScrollView onScroll={this.props.onScroll}>{this.renderScrollViewElements()}</ScrollView>
    )
  }
}


import React from 'react';
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navbarContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  menuContainer: {
    width: 80,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

    class Footer extends React.Component {

      render() {
        const { footerHeight } = this.props;

        return (
          <Animated.View style={[styles.navbarContainer, { height: this.props.footerHeight }]}>
            <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
               <Text>ABC</Text>
           </View>
          </Animated.View>
        );
      }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that the height of the footer is constant as 60. And even on scroll of the scrollview, it doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be careful with is that using the Animated API runs outside of the standard 'render' loop. This means that, in your Home component, when your *scrollY* gets updated, it doesn't necessarily call the *render()* method. This means that your footerHeight prop will never get through.

Since your Footer is an *Animated.View*, you should be sending footerHeight directly as a *style* object with height, as the *style* of an Animated component gets updated regardless if render() is called.

```
renderFooter = () => {
const footerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, FOOTER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
  outputRange: [FOOTER_MAX_HEIGHT, FOOTER_MIN_HEIGHT],
  extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
return (
      <Footer 
         style={{height: footerHeight}}>
      />
);
}
```